# Connect to printer on Windows PC via smb - authentication required

Tags: windows, printing, smb

I have laptop with macOS Sierra 10.12 and shared printer Kyocera_FS_1120MFP_GX which is connected to PC with Windows 7.

If I connect it directly to my laptop via USB it works, but if I try to connect it via local network it show me `Print queue` window with `Hold for Authentication`.

For other windows PCs it works ok.
I tried some commands in terminal:
`lpstat -p` shows `printer Kyocera_FS_1120MFP_GX is idle. Authentication required`

`lpstat -s` shows `default Kyocera_FS_1120MFP_GX: smb://ks2-pc/Kyocera%20FS_1120MFP%20GX`

Also I tried 
`sudo lpadmin -p Kyocera_FS_1120MFP_GX -o auth-info-required=negotiate`
but it change nothing.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure it out:
You should open `keychain access` tool and find there your printer name in the keys list and remove it.

After that open `Print queue` window and select in the top menu: `Printer` - `print test page`. 
Window with login password will appears. Print there username - `guest` without password. 
After that printer should work.

Comment: Finally an answer that worked, I tried everything without success till this. Thanks!